# Error using sjPlot::tab_model; Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors; when using unmarked pcount() function

Tags: r, sjplot, unmarked-package

Good morning,

I am modelling abundance using the pcount() function in the unmarked package and am receiving the error "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" when trying to create tables to summarize estimates, aics, etc. I have read some previous posts and have updated both insight and sjPlot using the github function. I was wondering if anyone could help.

Also welcome to any other packages/functions that would work with this model type.

```r
mhbdata <- read.csv("http://sites.google.com/site/unmarkedinfo/home/webinars/2012-january/data/wtmatrix.csv?attredirects=0&d=1%22")
y <- apply(mhbdata[, c("c.1", "c.2", "c.3")], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE) 
elev <- mhbdata[, "elev"] 
forest <- mhbdata[, "forest"]

library("unmarked") 
mhb.y <- mhbdata[, c("c.1", "c.2", "c.3")]
mhbdata[, "length"] <- 1 / mhbdata[, "length"]
mhb.umf <-
  unmarkedFramePCount(
    y = mhb.y,
    siteCovs = data.frame(
      elev = mhbdata[, "elev"],
      forest = mhbdata[, "forest"],
      length = mhbdata[, "length"]
    ),
    obsCovs = list(duration = mhbdata[, c("dur.1", "dur.2", "dur.3")], day = mhbdata[, c("day.1", "day.2", "day.3")])
  )

obsCovs(mhb.umf) <- scale(obsCovs(mhb.umf))
siteCovs(mhb.umf)$forest <- scale(siteCovs(mhb.umf)$forest)
siteCovs(mhb.umf)$elev <- scale(siteCovs(mhb.umf)$elev)
str(mhb.umf) 

fm1 <- pcount( ~ 1 ~ 1, mhb.umf)
fm2 <- pcount( ~ 1 ~ elev, mhb.umf)
fm3 <- pcount( ~ 1 ~ forest, mhb.umf)
fm4 <- pcount( ~ 1 ~ length, mhb.umf)
fm5 <- pcount( ~ 1 ~ forest + elev, mhb.umf)
fm6 <- pcount( ~ 1 ~ forest + length, mhb.umf)
fm7 <- pcount( ~ 1 ~ elev + length, mhb.umf)
fm8 <- pcount( ~ 1 ~ forest + elev + length, mhb.umf)
fm9 <- pcount( ~ 1 ~ elev + I(elev ^ 2), mhb.umf)
fm10 <- pcount( ~ 1 ~ forest + elev + I(elev ^ 2) + length, mhb.umf)
```

Thanks in advance,
Ty

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: Hey @Daniel, thank you for your response, this would be some example code for getting a pcount model:

mhbdata <- read.csv("http://sites.google.com/site/unmarkedinfo/home/webinars/2012-january/data/wtmatrix.csv?attredirects=0&d=1")

y<- apply(mhbdata[,c("c.1","c.2","c.3")],1,max,na.rm=TRUE)
elev<-mhbdata[,"elev"]
forest<-mhbdata[,"forest"]

Comment: Sorry new to stackoverflow, here is continued code:
library("unmarked")
mhb.y<-mhbdata[,c("c.1","c.2","c.3")]
mhbdata[,"length"]<-1/mhbdata[,"length"]
mhb.umf<-unmarkedFramePCount(y=mhb.y,
siteCovs=data.frame(elev=mhbdata[,"elev"],forest=mhbdata[,"forest"],length=mhbdata[,"length"]),
obsCovs=list(duration=mhbdata[,c("dur.1","dur.2","dur.3")],
             day = mhbdata[,c("day.1","day.2","day.3")])  )
obsCovs(mhb.umf)<- scale(obsCovs(mhb.umf))
siteCovs(mhb.umf)$forest<-scale(siteCovs(mhb.umf)$forest)
siteCovs(mhb.umf)$elev<-scale(siteCovs(mhb.umf)$elev)
str(mhb.umf)

Comment: fm1<- pcount(~1 ~1, mhb.umf)
fm2 <- pcount(~1 ~elev,mhb.umf)
fm3<- pcount(~1 ~forest,mhb.umf)
fm4<- pcount(~1 ~length,mhb.umf)
fm5<- pcount(~1 ~forest+elev,mhb.umf)
fm6<- pcount(~1 ~forest+length,mhb.umf)
fm7<- pcount(~1 ~elev+length,mhb.umf)
fm8<- pcount(~1 ~forest+elev+length,mhb.umf)
fm9<- pcount(~1 ~elev + I(elev^2),mhb.umf)
fm10<- pcount(~1 ~forest+elev+I(elev^2) + length,mhb.umf)

Comment: Just checked your example. `pcount()` objects have a very special structure, so these models are currently not supported by the sjPlot packages. I can try to implement support.

Comment: That would be awesome! Thank you so much, let me know how it goes.

Comment: If you like, you can follow the development here: https://github.com/easystats/insight/issues/187 (and discuss this issue as well)